# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params int[])' and 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco8

I tried recently to upgrade my website from U7.15.6 to U8. I just copied /bin /umbraco /config to my current website using FileZilla

When I tried to roll back to U7.15.6 I got the following error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params int[])' and 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params string[])' Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params int[])' and 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params string[])'

Source Error:

```
Line 20:    var section_node = Umbraco.Content(1xxx);    
Line 21:    var Section_pagesToList = @Section_node.Children.Where("Visible");
Line 22:    Section_pagesToList = Section_node.DescendantsOrSelf().Where("NodeTypeAlias == @0", "NewsPage");
```

So what I did, I changed Line 21 as follow:

```
string[] Section_pagesToList = @Section_node.Children.Where("Visible");
```

But now I'm getting another error in other part of the page - where I display the feature image of this section:

```
 Line 81:               <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-4 MainNewsBox">
Line 82:                    <figure>
Line 83:                        @if (Section_pagesToList.Last().HasValue("articleImg"))
```

The error in line 83 is:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1929: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue' and the best extension method overload 'PublishedContentExtensions.HasValue(IPublishedContent, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IPublishedContent'
```

How can I resolved it and bring my website back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to reinstall v7.15.6 to get the proper DLLs back, if you're not able to roll back via a VCS. Maybe take this opportunity to start using Nuget. With regards to v7 -> v8 there is no direct way to upgrade. On https://our.umbraco.com you can find more info on how to get migrated (!) to v8.

Comment: Hi, I already tried to roll back by deleting /bin /umbraco /umbraco_client /config etc. from my server and copy a new folders that I downloaded from our.umbraco - without success. Then, I tried to install locally using Visual Studio and Nuget, but when I pasted my .sdf to the local App_Data I got the error above also on local. Could it be that V8 has changed my DB?